# Update Python Dictionary with Tuple of Strings to set (key, value) fails

Tags: python, dictionary, grammar, iterable

[`dict.update([other])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) says

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from *other*, overwriting existing keys. Return *None*.
>
> update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs: d.update(red=1, blue=2).

But

```
>>> {}.update( ("key", "value") )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

So why does Python apparently try to use the first string of the tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument needs to be **an iterable of tuples** (or other iterables of length two), e.g. a list

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update([("key", "value")])
>>> d
{'key': 'value'}
```

or a tuple, however this fails:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update((("key", "value")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

The [Python documentation on `tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) again solves this mystery:

> Note that it is actually the comma which makes a tuple, not the parentheses. The parentheses are optional, except in the empty tuple case, or when they are needed to avoid syntactic ambiguity.

I.e. `(None)` is not a tuple at all, but `(None,)` is:

```
>>> type( (None,) )
<class 'tuple'>
```

So this works:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update((("key", "value"),))
>>> d
{'key': 'value'}
>>>
```

You can't omit the parentheses because

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(("key", "value"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

that would be said *syntactic ambiguity* (comma is function argument separator).